# Converting and formattig variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I have successfully changed all 3 variables to numeric but I am only getting . in the price1 column.

```
  data lalisting_new;
  set aa_lbhw1.lalisting;
  price1 = input(price, 10.0);
  format price dollar10.0;
  host_response_rate1 = input(host_response_rate, 3.);
  host_acceptance_rate1 = input(host_acceptance_rate, 3.);
  drop price host_response_rate host_acceptance_rate;
  run;
```

Comment: Please post sample data so we can see why this is happening.

Comment: The dot simply means "missing", i.e. the value of price could not be converted to a number.

Comment: Assigning a format to a variable you then drop is useless. Formats only impact the way data is displayed.

Comment: Did you mean to format `price1`?  How ever if that variable's values is always missing (`.`), the format won't help.  There is a problem with `price` -- How is data set  `aa_lbhw1.lalisting` made or input ? Show your code and log messages.

Answer (score 0):

If PRICE has commas and dollar signs (like would be produced by the DOLLAR format) then use the COMMA informat instead of the basic numeric informat.

Note that the only reason to use a short width on the informat (like the 10 and 3 in your example) would be if the string held some non-digit characters after that number of characters.  If the whole string is to be converted into the number then just use the maximum width the informat supports as the INPUT() function does not care if the informat width is larger than the length of the string being read.

```
data lalisting_new;
  set aa_lbhw1.lalisting;
  price1 = input(price, comma32.);
  host_response_rate1 = input(host_response_rate,32.);
  host_acceptance_rate1 = input(host_acceptance_rate,32.);
  drop price host_response_rate host_acceptance_rate;
  format price1 dollar10.0;
run;
```